# Backbone Validate does not work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone's `validate` function to guarantee `Man` to have an `age` property more than 18. Here is my code:

```
var Man = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.on("error",function(model,error){
            alert(error);
        });
    },
    validate : function(attrs,options){
        if (attrs.age < 18){
            return 'below 18';
        } 
    }
})

var man = new Man({name : 'qian', age : 12});
```

But looking at the result it seems that `validate` doesn't work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Backbone.js (prior to version `0.9.10`), `validate` is called before `save` as well as before `set`.

You will get an *alert* error when you set *invalid* value.

Example - *`age` value is below 18* :

```
var man = new Man ({name : 'qian', age : 12});
man.set({ age: 12 }); // that will trigger alert
```

**EDIT**

For Backbone.js version `0.9.10+` there is an issue reported: [Failed validation does not trigger error callback](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2153). Issue explanation says that

> `invalid` event should be used instead of `error`

So changing your code to:

```
var Man = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.on("invalid",function(model,error){
            alert(error);
        });
    },
    ...
```

And setting variable with `validate` option set to `true` will trigger an `alert`.

```
man.set({age: 12}, {validate : true});
```

Comment: Which version of Backbone.js do you use? That behaviour has change with 0.9.10

Comment: you got it !0.9.10,so what should I do ,then

Comment: Yowch. Dislike the option requirement!! https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2174

Comment: so you now have to explicitly tell backbone to validate? Seems a little sucky!!

Comment: Thanks! Was just about to post a question about this :)

Answer (score 8):

For backbone v.1.0.0

```
var Man = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.on("invalid",function(model,error){
            alert(error);
        });
    },
    validate : function(attrs, options){
        if (attrs.age < 18){
            return 'below 18';
        } 
    }
});
```

#### Example 1. Without {validate:true}

```
//Object will be created with invalid attribute 'age' 
var man = new Man({name : 'qian', age : 12});
console.log(man) // Returns an object with invalid attributes

// But we'll use only valid objects.
// Also we'll get the error message in alert, if validation fails.
if(man.isValid()){
    alert( man.get('name') );
}

var man = new Man({name : 'qian', age : 19});
if(man.isValid()){
    alert( man.get('name') );
}
```

#### Example 2. With {validate:true}

```
//Object will be created without any passed attributes
var man = new Man({name : 'qian', age : 12}, {validate:true});
console.log(man) //Object will be without passed attributes

/* man.isValid() returns 'true' throw we passed invalid attrs.
   We won't see any error alert message, because Backbone created empty object */
/* Doesn't work */
if(man.isValid()){
    alert( man.get('name') ); //undefined
}
/* Works */
// Created model had invalid attrs, so validationError won't be empty.
// If all attrs are valid, validationError will be empty
if(!man.validationError){
    alert( man.get('name') );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using new version(>1.0) of Backbone and want to fire validation at the time of `model.set` method,

then you must have to pass `{validate: true}` to fire validation.

use

```
model.set({field:value},{validate: true})
```

OR

```
model.set("field","value",{validate: true})
```

instead of

```
model.set({field:value})
```

REF : [Backbone change log](http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading)

Answer (score 3):

```
var man = new Man({name : 'qian', age : 12}, {validate : true});
```

**EDIT:**

validate method works only in case if you pass an options object with `validate` param (from 0.9.9 version):
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L539

And it triggers not `error` event but `invalid` event