# Backbone.js Model Validation Not Working

Tags: backbone.js, model-validation

What's wrong with the following code?

```
(function(){

    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    };

    App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            title: '',
            priority: 0
        },

        validate: function(attrs, options){
            if (attrs.priority < 0){
                return 'Priority cannot be negative.';
            }
        }
    });

    var task = new App.Models.Task ({ title: 'Sample Task', priority: 5 });
    task.on('invalid', function(model, error) { console.log(error); })

    task.save({ priority: -9 }); // Should not pass validation
    console.log(task.validationError); // Prints a validation error

    console.log(task.toJSON()); // Model is updated with -9
    console.log(task.isValid()); // false
})();
```

Output:

```
Priority cannot be negative. app.js:27
Priority cannot be negative. app.js:30
Object {title: "Sample Task", priority: -9} app.js:32
Priority cannot be negative. app.js:27
false
```

I am currently watching a video tutorial and it's based on old version of backbone.js where validation was by default enforced on the `set` method. But in the current version validation is by default enforced on the `save` method.

But even though it's not a valid value and the validation doesn't pass why is it still setting the value to -9. Isn't it supposed to not set the value when the validation doesn't pass?

Comment: What are you in fact expecting ? You set a negative priority, so you don't pass the validation, so..? (btw isn't the 4th line in the Output right? I feel like it shouldn't be here)

Comment: Isn't it not supposed to set the value to -9 as the validation doesn't pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new version, when saving new data, you need to pass the validation option:

```
task.save({ priority: -9 }, {validation: true});
```

Comment: I'm curious to know where you found that. *Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default upon construction or in Model#set, unless the {validate:true} option is passed.* Backbone 0.9.10

Comment: Oh, and it 1.0's code: *options = _.extend({validate: true}, options);* Model#save.

Comment: When i was doing some Backbone work before, I came across the same situation.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426155/backbone-validate-does-not-work ..my sources came around these types of answers

Comment: Better look at Backbone's doc & change logs to know what's truly in the "new" version. Still, we'll know better when Zuhaib adds some precision.

Comment: The backbone doc says validation is by default  available upon the Save method, where as you need to manually pass {validate:true} when calling the set method.

Why is it setting the value to -9 even though it's not a valid value.

Comment: @ashley validation don't work in the constructor, that's clearly mentioned in the docs. But it should work in the `save` method, which it isn't.

Comment: I agree with Ashley's answer. If you pass {validate: true} the negative number does not get passed to the object and 5 remains intact.I just tested the code and it worked

Answer (score 6):

in the current version of Backbone.js:

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true} is passed.

So, in order to have this method called on your method, you should set validate to true when setting a property on your model like so:

```
yourmodel.set('someproperty', 14, {validate: true});
```

I hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the code from the official site. Looking at the source of `save` function I understand that presetting of `options.validate` to `true` happens AFTER the `set` is called.

You can try to switch the order of lines (in `save` function of `Model`):

```
  if (attrs && (!options || !options.wait) && !this.set(attrs, options)) return false;

  options = _.extend({validate: true}, options);
```

to:

```
   options = _.extend({validate: true}, options);

   if (attrs && (!options || !options.wait) && !this.set(attrs, options)) return false;
```

but I am not sure it won't break something else.

OR you can use the code from GitHub repo - there is a change that solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you simply need to set the flag 'wait' to true OR set the 'validate' flag to true. How is it? Well, if you don't set the wait flag to true, the set method will be called with the options you passed the save method BEFORE the validation. So as you didn't need to pass the validate flag, the set method doesn't receive it, don't run the validation, and set the attributes.
As the doc isn't clear about the wait flag: your server will still receive the updated data.