# Backbone: my validation is not stopping white space being set to value

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've been following a tutorial on Backbone and have my Tasks project setup here:

**http://leongaban.com/_pro/**

Now in my single Task View I had a validation bug, which I [found out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426155/backbone-validate-does-not-work) that I needed to have {validation: true}

It works in that it prevents the user from entering in a null value (ie: deleting the current value) however I can't stop the user from entering only spaces

My Model and validate method:

```
App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attrs) {

        var errors = this.errors = {};

        if (attrs.title != null) {

            console.log('title is not null');

            if ($.trim(attrs.title) == null) {
                alert('error');
                console.log('title is required');
            }
        }

        // if ( $.trim(!attrs.title) ) {
        //  return false;
        // }
    }
});
```

This is where you get to set a new value:

```
editTask: function() {
        var newTaskTitle = prompt(this.msgPrompt, this.model.get('title'));

        // check for null value
        if ( !newTaskTitle ) return;

        console.log(newTaskTitle);
        this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle, { validate : true });
    },
```

[If you notice in my example](http://leongaban.com/_pro/) you can change the value and it works, or try and delete and submit a null value and the validate will stop it, however how would you efficiently not change the value if the user adds just white space?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> **validate** `model.validate(attributes, options)`
>
> [...] If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from **validate**; if they are invalid, return an error of your choosing. It can be as simple as a string error message to be displayed, or a complete error object that describes the error programmatically.

The `validate` in your question never returns anything so it will never catch invalid values.

And [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) works on strings, not booleans so I don't know what this:

```
if ( $.trim(!attrs.title) ) {
  return false;
}
```

is intended to do.

If your `validate` look more like this:

```
validate: function(attrs) {
    var errors = { };
    if('title' in attrs) {
        // Adjust this if you want to allow `null` values.
        if($.trim(attrs.title || '') === '') {
            errors.title = 'Missing title';
        }
    }
    return _(errors).isEmpty() ? undefined : errors;
}
```

then perhaps you'd get better results.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/p9ah5/

Some notes:

1. I use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to see if `attrs` has a `'title'` key with any value. The value could be `null` or `false` or `0` or `'pancakes'` or ... we don't care what the value is, we just care if it is there so we use `in` to say exactly what we mean.
2. You seem to want the error messages in an object so we populate an object and use [`_.isEmpty`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty) to see if we put anything it, then we'll know what we should return.
3. Backbone will put the errors in [`validationError`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validationError) so there's no need for the `this.error` stuff.

Comment: Ah thanks for the more comprehensive explanation, I'm so use to checking stackoverflow for questions, always forget the docs these days :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out!

I guess I'll just use the validation method for more comprehensive testing, but to check for null or white spaces this is suffice inside of the **task view**:

```
editTask: function() {
    var newTaskTitle = prompt(this.msgPrompt, this.model.get('title'));

    // check for null value
    if ( ! $.trim(newTaskTitle) ) return;

    console.log(newTaskTitle);
    this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle, { validate : true });
},
```